# What is the best way to find which NSPoint another NSPoint is closest to?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, distance, nspoint

I have 4 NSPoints, which are 4 corners of a rectangle

Now I have another NSPoint, which is where the mouse goes down (*mousedown_nsp*).

What is the best way for me to find the closest NSPoint (out of the 4 rectangle corner NSPoints) in relation to *mousedown_nsp*?

I was thinking of just doing a comparison to find the distance between *mousedown_nsp* and the other 4 NSPoints, then choosing the smallest distance, but I feel like there has got to be a better way.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In order to find a minimum, you have to compare against all other values. There's no way around it. (You can try to refactor the loop into a functional-style something if that's your taste, but you can't really do it faster than `O(n)`.)

Comment: Think of it this way - take your rectangle and split it into four equal quadrants. Which ever of the 4 quadrants your point lies in, the point will be closest to that corner. No need to calculate actual distances. It's fairly simple if the rectangle is not rotated at all.

Comment: @rmaddy , so I should create 4 smaller rectangles around the 4 corners, and find which rectangle the mouse is in?  Is there a method I could call that finds whether or not a point lies within a rectangle?

Comment: @MattyAyOh Please **use Google.** `NSRectContainsPoint()` is your friend.

Comment: @user3477950 Such function does not exist. `NSPointInRect` is the correct name.

Comment: How would you define "better way"? I see no problem with taking the point whose squared distance to mousedown_nsp is least.

Comment: @Jessy, I just wanted to use the best practice because I'm new and want to learn.  That was what I originally had, but it felt too easy and I wasn't sure if there was a more efficient way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this (this assumes a non-rotated rectangle):

```
NSPoint tl = ... // top-left corner
NSPoint tr = ... // top-right corner
NSPoint bl = ... // bottom-left corner
NSPoint br = ... // bottom-right corner
NSPoint pt = ... // the point

NSPoint center = NSMakePoint((tl.x + tr.x) / 2.0, (tl.y + bl.y) / 2.0);
NSPoint closest;
if (pt.x < center.x) {
    if (pt.y < center.y) {
        closest = tl; // point is in upper-left quadrant
    } else {
        closest = bl; // point is in lower-left quadrant
    }
} else {
    if (pt.y < center.y) {
        closest = tr; // point is in upper-right quadrant
    } else {
        closest = br; // point is in lower-right quadrant
    }
}
```